# Замена значений в датафрейме

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, почему когда я пытаюсь заменить во фрейме значения по нужной мне логике, где-то происходит сбой и замена совершется некорректно?

Вот, например, в ряду

```
1   5   3   2   4   4   2
3   4   3   3   3   3   3
```

я хочу заменить значения так, чтоб:

- если разницы между верхним и нижним числом == 1, то нижнее число заменялось на 3
- если разницы между верхним и нижним числом == 2, то нижнее число заменялось на 2
- если разницы между верхним и нижним числом == 3, то нижнее число заменялось на 1
- если разницы между верхним и нижним числом == 4, то нижнее число заменялось на 0
  А если верхнее и нижнее совпадают, то ставить 4.

Внизу должен получиться ряд чисел

```
2   3   4   3   3   3   3
```

но я получаю почему-то

```
2   0   4   3   3   3   3
```

Второй столбик заменяется некорректно, и я понять не могу, почему.

```
res = df.applymap(lambda x:x.lower() if type(x) == str else x)
res[abs(res.iloc[0]-res)==1]=3
res[abs(res.iloc[0]-res)==2]=2
res[abs(res.iloc[0]-res)==3]=1
res[abs(res.iloc[0]-res)==4]=0

res[res==res.iloc[0]]=4

res.loc[0] = df.loc[0]
```

Целый фрейм, а не демонстративный кусок, здесь

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QyCqM8_9XOgbsRVL8_YmqnE8pW0KNn5VOJ7WSE878_k/edit?usp=sharing

---

Пример побольше. Первая строка- это числа, в соответствии с которыми рассчитываются и заменяются остальные числа в столбце.
Было:

```
1   5   3   2   4
3   4   3   3   3
1   5   1   1   1
1   5   1   1   3
```

Должно стать:

```
1   5   3   2   4
2   3   4   3   3
4   4   2   3   1
4   4   2   3   3
```

Если переформулировать: Первая числовая строка - это ключевое значение, в соответствие с которым пересчитывается все остальные числовые значения. Если число соответствует ключу, то оно заменяется на "4". Во всех остальных случаях числа будут заменяться по формуле |ключевое значение - значение в столбце| -1

Comment: ваш фрейм состоит из 2 строк?

Comment: Нет, он большой. Это просто для примера, чтоб не захламлять. Сейчас выложу целый фрейм

Comment: тогда вообще непонятно что должно происходить с остальными строками. Можете привести пример с 4-мя строками и результат, который хотите получить?

Comment: Да, попробую привести пример. Но если кратко: Первая числовая строка - это ключевое значение, в соответствие с которым пересчитывается все остальные числовые значения. Если число соответствует ключу, то оно заменяется на "4". Во всех остальных случаях числа будут заменяться по формуле |ключевое значение - значение в столбце| -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, ну вполне понятно, что происходит, если я правильно понял, что вы вообще делаете:

> 5 - 4 = 1, срабатывает условие `res[abs(res.iloc[0]-res)==1]=3`,
> 4 заменяется на 3
>
> 5 - 3 = 2, срабатывает условие `res[abs(res.iloc[0]-res)==2]=2`,
> 3 заменяется на 2
>
> 5 - 2 = 1, срабатывает условие `res[abs(res.iloc[0]-res)==3]=1`,
> 2 заменяется на 1
>
> 5 - 1 = 4, срабатывает условие `res[abs(res.iloc[0]-res)==4]=0`,
> 1 заменяется на 0

Таким образом 4 после применения этих четырёх строк кода последовательно превращается в 3, 2, 1 и, наконец, 0.

Наверное, это можно починить, если сохранить `abs(res.iloc[0]-res)` в какую-то переменную и использовать её в данных проверках, чтобы изменённое значение не просачивалось тут же в проверку условий на последующих строках.

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на мою ошибку! Удалось починить!